# Colors of the Parah Adumah

Tags: color, parah-adumah

Consider the following opinions of what adumah can or does in fact mean.

Sadia gaon writes that Aduma of the Parah Adumah is 'Tzafra'. The footnote from Rav Kapach in the Mosad Rav Cook edition explains this means yellow, like an egg yolk.

Torah Temimah on the first passuk in chukas #8 [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.19.2?lang=bi) Adumah could have meant black, if not for the fact that the Torah specifies temimah.

Does anyone else suggest any other colors adumah might mean?

Comment: From the gemara in Masheches Avodah zarah 24a it seems red is the color

Comment: Consider that the colour palettes might not be the same for words in Tanakh as it is for us. Adom means red/brown (not a mix, but either!) in many ancient Semitic languages.

Comment: consider the extremely precise terminology in this mishnah:  https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Parah.2.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

Comment: Which “Mosad Rav Kook edition” of Saadia Gaon are you citing? In the Torat Haim *chumash* from MRK they utilized the Qafih edition together with the latter’s notes. There R’ Qafih translates the Arabic to “reddish” on the basis of Targum on Job, not “yellow”.

Comment: @Oliver I've edited that it's Rav Kapach. He says it's like chelmon from an egg. The yolk.

Comment: I now see why the discrepancy. The *chumash* Torat Haim does not offer the full more of R’ Qafih. His ed., pub. by MRK Perushe Rabbenu Saadia Gaon 1988, has a longer note which contains your citation. (Though reading his longer note in the latter, I’m confused myself where he writes “....וכן וכו׳”.)